# New network card in server 14.04

Tags: networking

I must install a new network card in the zentyal 4.2 server based on Ubuntu 14.04

How can I reconfigure the network so that the new card is working and the server could be connect to the network again.

On the previous release ( 12.04 ) this could be done by editing the file:

```
nano /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

And delete the last two lines, after a reboot the network is operational again.

In the release 14.04 I could not find this file, so what to do about installation of a new network card ?

Comment: I don't have such a server available right now, but I'd expect to find some file with a similar name (different number?)

Comment: This is a problem in ubuntu server 16.04

Comment: You said "zentyal"...

Comment: Yes, I use Zentyal server based on ubuntu server 14.04 but the network drivers are ubuntu and not Zentyal. So this is realy a ubuntu question NICs' are driven by ubuntu. Dest regards Ian